# Fetch data from mapping table if the condition matches in multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql

```
product_id   property_id

1            2
1            5
2            2
3            5
```

I have a mapping table as above. I want to get only product with `id =1` if `product_id in (2,5)`. i.e. I want to fetch data if the table contains both `2,5` not the data if it is with `property_id` only `2 or 5`

```
select group_concat(distinct product_id) product_ids from table where property_id in (2,5)
```

UPDATE:
The property_id in can be property_id in(2,5,....). I get output from form as 2,5,.... and so on. Its not just for the single case. I just want the output if the condition in property_id in matches the whole series.

Answer (score 1):

This how it could be done

```
select
product_id from
table_name 
where property_id in (2,5)
group by product_id 
having count(*) = 2
```

All you need to change `having count(*) = 2` to the number of items inside `IN()` , right now its 2 and if you are looking at 3 property id then it will be 3 and so on.

Comment: Using group_by won't work..What if I have multiple product_id with matching conditions..

Comment: Yes if there are multiple match then it will return those items as well.

Comment: Please update the question with more sample data and what exactly you are looking at, right now for given sample data and question the above query is the answer !!

Comment: Yea It works.I had already done what you have done before posting this question..I was looking for group_concat..With this I have to use extra logic to make them to use as ID IN in next query..thank you..

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct a.product_id 
from table a, table b
where a.product_id = b.product_id
and a.property_id = 2
and b.property_id = 5
```

Comment: It works if there is only two conditions but the conditions is dynamic, it can be more of the series..1,2,3,... and so on.